# Isolate the word in quotes ( C# )

Tags: c#, regex

Help me. I spend a lot of time and all to no avail.
It necessary to isolate a string of three words, and the last word should be in quotes and inside should be no spaces.
 for instance, from string :

> *Something text **set vrouter "Untrust-Gi"** something text*

i need  (in С# )

> set vrouter "Untrust-Gi"

look ,please, code.If possible, correct the code. I added it to my question

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(opendialog.FileName);
            string pattern = @"(\w+\s){2}(""\S+?"")";
            while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                var match=Regex.Matches(sr, pattern);

                textBox1.AppendText(match.ReadLine()+'\n');


            }

        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to match a pattern in text?

Comment: I beg  help make the right pattern ))

Comment: Which patterns you already tried that didn't work?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for `set vrouter "string"` or you want to get the word in quotes plus the two preceeding words ?

Comment: At first so: set vrouter "string"

Comment: string 'set vrouter "Untrust-Gi"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var match = Regex.Match(yourStringHere, @"(\w+\s){2}(""\S+?"")");
if(match.Success)
    result = match.Value;
```

\S means "not a space" so it answers your "inside should be no spaces" requirement.

EDIT: here is your code after correction, you didn't specified the file size, so maybe there are better ways to read it...

```
OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName);
        string pattern = @"(\w+\s){2}(""\S+?"")";
        foreach(var line in lines)
        {
            var matches= Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
            foreach(Match match in matches)
            {
                if(match.Success)
                textBox1.AppendText(match.Value+'\n');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If possible, correct the code. I added it to my question

Comment: Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Success' and no extension method 'Success' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: match has not property Success/

Comment: @user3214034 Sorry, little mistake, it is "Match match in matches", I correct it immediatly

Comment: Thank you! basically everything is fine! However, your regular season isolates any three words and the last quoted. And I need only set vrouter "something_word"/
but thank you very much for methodic using of regular expressions!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the expression inside the quotes is always preceded by "set vrouter", you can use this regular expression

```
set vrouter \"(.*)\"
```

and then extract the sequence obtained in the capture group `(.*)`

Test your expressions using the following tools

http://regexpal.com/

http://www.regexper.com/

Once you have the extracted expression, you can quite easily re-build the string in C#.

```
var value = String.Format("set vrouter \"{0}\"", extractedExpression);
```

Comment: This will fail/missmatch on `Something text set vrouter "Untrust-Gi" something "text"`

Comment: @stema...I was concerned about this, however since it does not have ^ and $ to denote start and end of string, it seems to match OK. I tested the expression with regexpal.com, and it matched OK with leading and trailing text.

Comment: I'll check it all! Thank you all for participating!

Comment: @stema - I see your point now...the addition of more quotes breaks the expression...back to the drawing board